# check distribution version linux with ip

Tags: server, ip

For a quiz I must fill in the following question:
Which distribution of Linux is on the server. They give me only a ip adress "37.59.41.190". How can I check this external?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nmap` command to find Operating System details, it's not 100% accurate, though,

```
nmap -O <ip address>
```

nmap runs different OS fingerprint check techniques.